# Increment individual IPs from IPv6 string (php)

Tags: php, ipv6

What is a simple, elegant way to list the first x number of IPv6 IPs from a IPv6 string.

For example,

listIPs("2600:f333:10:c000::0", 4)

echos

- 2600:f333:10:c000::1
- 2600:f333:10:c000::2
- 2600:f333:10:c000::3
- 2600:f333:10:c000::4

Here's a sample of code that may have worked for IPv4, as it converted to int:

```
$input = "2600:f333:10:c000::/51";
$max = 4;

list($block, $cidr) = explode("/", $input);

$first = inet_pton( $block );
echo inet_ntop($first) . "\n";

for ($i = 1; $i < $max; $i++) {
   //todo: die if it has exceeded block size based on $cidr
   echo inet_ntop($first + $i) . "\n"; //doesn't work, packed binary?
}
```

Comment: note that an ipv6 address with a CIDR suffix of 51 describes a range of 1,5111572745183E+23 addresses. you can calculate this number as follows: `echo pow(2, (128 - 51));`

Comment: hmmm, not pow(2, 64-51) ?  I thought /64 was the smallest.  http://www.ripe.net/internet-coordination/press-centre/understanding-ip-addressing

Comment: No ipv6 uses 128 bit addresses. A laaaaaaarge address space :)

Comment: Ok, thanks for the clarification.  The question can stand as is though, I'd really like to get a listing of each /64, and I can adjust the code as necessary for /128!

Comment: I'm preparing an example

Comment: @divitiae: Listing an entire /64 is impossible -- there are 2^64 (about 18 quintillion) addresses in the range, and storing the results would require a significant percentage (if not all) of the disk storage available in the world.

Comment: @divitiae: The output would be about 528 EiB if I have calculated correctly (assuming one address per line and no '::' notation). Given that current human-produced information is estimated as 12 EiB it might take some space.

Comment: So if you just want a listing of each /64 then your example should show: `2600:f333:10:c000::/51 -> 2600:f333:10:c001::/64, 2600:f333:10:c002::/64 2600:f333:10:c003::/64 2600:f333:10:c004::/64 2600:f333:10:c005::/64`, etc.

Comment: I'll readily admit that I'm far from an expert at C++, but the code you posted(aside from a syntax error on the line inside the `for` loop, the paren should be before the last concatenation) seems pretty sound. That assumes that the `inet_ntop` and `inet_pton` commands return expected values. All of that said, is there any reason you can't convert to longhand CIDR notation and parse each octet (or whatever the name is now) separately?

Comment: @lunchmeat317 Thats PHP code ;)

Comment: @duskwuff I'm out of disk... :)

Comment: @hek2mgl Oh, man! *facepalm* Somehow, I really can't believe I missed that. I knew there was something bugging me about the raw call to that linux command, but the logic made sense. On the bright side, I guess I'm now reading logic instead of syntax. I guess it was bound to happen jumping between many different languages. My bad! :P

Comment: @lunchmeat317 No only. the question was tagged C, C++. I've dropped the tags ;)

Comment: Actually, I really don't care what language it is in as long as I can call it from linux command line.

Comment: @duskwuff I should expect exactly 8192 results if I'm looking for every /64 range in a /51, right?  We can try something like:  listranges(start, incrementSubnet, maxResults = 100000)

Comment: @divitiae: Are you trying to list subnets or IPs? The example output in your question shows the first three IPs in the range, not subnets.

Comment: @duskwuff Yes, let's simplify and get rid of subnets all together, I've updated the question...

Comment: something like inet_ntop(decbin(bindec($first) + $i)) seems like it should work, but doesn't.

Comment: @divitiae: So long as you're sticking with trying to list IPv6 IPs, my point stands -- there are far too many of them in any network to list.

Comment: @duskwuff "list the first x number of IPv6 IPs from a string given"... let x = 2.  It'd help to just know how I could unpack whatever inet_pton gives me, add 1, display it as a IPv6 again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example program written in C (since I don't know C++). It's fairly fast, but I'm not really happy with it. Maybe someone can help me improve it.

**Edit:** Obviously, I wrote this before it was turned into a PHP-only question. Turning this into PHP is left as an exercise to the reader (ew).

```c
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

/*
 * Syntax: ./ipv6_list <ip>/<cidr-prefix>
 */
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    uint8_t start[16];
    uint8_t address[16];
    uint8_t mask[16] = { 0 };

    uint8_t prefix = 128;
    char *prefix_location;

    int i;

    /* This is the octet that, when changed, will result in <IP> & <mask> != <start IP> */
    int mask_check_octet = 0;

    if(argc != 2)
        return 1;

    /* Find prefix */
    if((prefix_location = strstr(argv[1], "/")) != NULL) {
        char *prefix_search = prefix_location + 1;
        char *prefix_remaining;
        long prefix_test;

        if(!isdigit(*prefix_search))
            return 2;

        errno = 0;
        prefix_test = strtol(prefix_search, &prefix_remaining, 10);
        if(errno == ERANGE || prefix_test < 0 || prefix_test > 128 || strcmp(prefix_remaining, "") != 0)
            return 2;

        prefix = (uint8_t)prefix_test;
        *prefix_location = '\0'; /* So we can just pass argv[1] into inet_pton(3) */
    }

    /* Convert prefix into mask */
    for(i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
        if(prefix == 0)
            break;

        mask_check_octet = i;
        if(prefix < 8) {
            mask[i] = ~((1 << (8 - prefix)) - 1);
            break;
        }
        else
            mask[i] = UINT8_MAX;

        prefix -= 8;
    }

    /* Find address */
    if(inet_pton(AF_INET6, argv[1], start) != 1)
        return 3;

    /* Start at the beginning of the network */
    for(i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
        start[i] &= mask[i];
        address[i] = start[i];
    }

    /* Iterate */
    while((address[mask_check_octet] & mask[mask_check_octet]) == start[mask_check_octet]) {
        char address_str[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];
        inet_ntop(AF_INET6, address, address_str, sizeof(address_str));
        printf("%s\n", address_str);

        /* Add one to the address */
        for(i = 15; i >= 0; i--) {
            if(address[i] != UINT8_MAX)
                break;
        }
        address[i]++;
        for(i++; i < 16; i++)
            address[i] = 0;
    };

    return 0;
}
```

You can use standard shell commands to limit its output (or just modify the `while` loop):

```
nfontes@brioche:~$ ./ipv6_list '2607:fc50:0:d00::0/106' | head -n 200
2607:fc50:0:d00::
2607:fc50:0:d00::1
2607:fc50:0:d00::2
2607:fc50:0:d00::3
2607:fc50:0:d00::4
2607:fc50:0:d00::5
2607:fc50:0:d00::6
2607:fc50:0:d00::7
2607:fc50:0:d00::8
2607:fc50:0:d00::9
2607:fc50:0:d00::a
2607:fc50:0:d00::b
2607:fc50:0:d00::c
2607:fc50:0:d00::d
2607:fc50:0:d00::e
[...]
2607:fc50:0:d00::c0
2607:fc50:0:d00::c1
2607:fc50:0:d00::c2
2607:fc50:0:d00::c3
2607:fc50:0:d00::c4
2607:fc50:0:d00::c5
2607:fc50:0:d00::c6
2607:fc50:0:d00::c7
```

Answer (score 1):

Something similar (in PHP). It takes an IPv4/IPv6 address and increments it by given value:

```
// Takes an IPv4/IPv6 address in string format, and increments it by given value
function incrementIp($ip, $increment)
{
  $addr = inet_pton ( $ip );

  for ( $i = strlen ( $addr ) - 1; $increment > 0 && $i >= 0; --$i )
  {
    $val = ord($addr[$i]) + $increment;
    $increment = $val / 256;
    $addr[$i] = chr($val % 256);
  }

  return inet_ntop ( $addr );
}
```